# Overriding Go's default HTTP Sever redirect behaviour

Tags: http, go

Go's default HTTP server implementation merges slashes in HTTP requests, returning an HTTP redirect response to the "cleaned" path:

https://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/pkg/net/http/server.go#1420

So if you make a HTTP request `GET /http://foo.com/`, the server responds with `301 Moved Permanently ... Location: /http:/foo.com/`.

I'd like to disable this behaviour and handle all paths myself.

I'm a Go newbie, and it seems as if I could create my own `Server` instance and override the `Handler` attribute, but I'm not sure how to?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I'd like to disable this behaviour and handle all paths myself.
>
> I'm a Go newbie, and it seems as if I could create my own Server instance and override the Handler attribute, but I'm not sure how to?

Instead of registering handlers with the `http.DefaultServeMux` through the `http.Handle` or `http.HandleFunc` methods just call:

```
http.ListenAndServe(":8080", MyHandler)
```

where `MyHandler` is an instance of a type that implements the [`http.Handler`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Handler) interface.

[`http.ListenAndServe`](http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/http/server.go?s=46958:47013#L1585) in turn is just a short-hand method that does the following:

```
func ListenAndServe(addr string, handler http.Handler) error {
    server := &http.Server{Addr: addr, Handler: handler}
    return server.ListenAndServe()
}
```

so you could do that directly instead as well.

Inside your handler you can then parse/route the URI however you wish like this:

```
func (h *MyHandlerType) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    uri := r.URL.Path
    // ...use uri...
}
```

Comment: Wow, that turned out to be really easy - I'll spend some more time reading up on interfaces and types! Here is the implementation I ended up with: https://gist.github.com/johnboxall/5698940

Comment: @jb. you don't need empty struct, closure will do https://gist.github.com/tsenart/5fc18c659814c078378d